# Searchin in a stack

Tags: c, search, stack

This is my code for the searching part and it's not working. Can you give me a little help on this? I'm newbie on programming and I really just suck at pointers. Thanks.

```
typedef struct Dictionary_Entry{
    int index;
    char character[100];
    struct Dictionary_Entry *link;
}Dictionary_Entry;

typedef struct Dictionary{
    Dictionary_Entry *top;
}Dictionary;

int check_in_dictionary(Dictionary *dictionary, char string[100], char file_char[100]){
    Dictionary_Entry *runner = dictionary->top;
    strcat(string, file_char);
        while(runner != NULL){
            if((strcmp(string, runner->character)) == 0){
                break;
                return runner->index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Show the `Dictionary` and `Dictionary_Entry` structures

Comment: if `runner->character` is a `char` instead of a string (`char[]`) then you cannot compare `string` with `runner->character`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version with my comments starting with `////`

```
int check_in_dictionary(Dictionary *dictionary, char string[100], char file_char[100]){
    Dictionary_Entry *runner = dictionary->top;
    strcat(string, file_char);
    while(runner != NULL){
      if((strcmp(string, runner->character)) == 0){
         return runner->index;  // found
         //// break not neccessary here as return returns anyway
      }
      runner = runner->link ;  //// goto next entry
    }
    return -1;
}
```

BTW `strcat(string, file_char);` is not necessary, you could compare directy to `file_char` like this `strcmp(file_char, runner->character)`

Answer (score 2):

The `break` keyword leaves the loop, so your `return runner->index` line doesn't get executed.  Swap the two lines (or remove `break`, since `return` will *also* leave the loop, in its way), and you should be fine.

Comment: it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: Weird.  It looks right, now.  Before the `if` statement, throw in some debugging to see what it's doing.  Something like `printf("(%s) (%s) (%d)\n", string, runner->character, strcmp(string, runner->character));` will tell you if the strings are right and whether the comparison is successful.  With code this simple, the problem must be in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the Dictionay in while loop.
something like this:

```
 while(runner != NULL){
        if((strcmp(string, runner->character)) == 0){
            return runner->index;
        }
    runner = runner->next; /* go to next element in dictionary */
    }
```